# Does Google penalize 301 redirects from my naked domain?

Tags: seo, dns, search-engine, google-search

Does Google Search and other search engines penalize 301 redirects from my naked domain to my regular domain? I need such redirect from `example.com` to `www.example.com` because Google App Engine does not support naked domains. If possible, please provide answers with updated references. Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, you will not be penalised. Google actually recommends that you set a preferred domain:

> Note: Once you've set your preferred
>   domain, you may want to use a 301
>   redirect to redirect traffic from your
>   non-preferred domain, so that other
>   search engines and visitors know which
>   version you prefer.

Source: http://www.google.com/support/webmasters/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=44231